# How to overcome SagePay payment processing error

Tags: c#, razor-pages, opayo

I am working on a web app using C# and Razor pages 2.2. I am experiencing this strange error with SagePay when all of the necessary information is provided properly:
[transaction error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs9Jr.png)

I debugged and notificationURL is getting passed properly. If I pass a wrong URL then a proper error message is also returned by SagePay.

Below detail is returned by SagePay on initiating a transaction:

Status : OK
Status Detail: The Transaction was Registered Successfully. 
NextURL : https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection?vpstxid={1E2EDF75-7671-171C-ED0C-509F8CB6A0B1}

SagePay throws error at the last step of payment processing.

Please note that NotificationURL property is set properly to site's page: 
https://www.xyz.co.uk/notificationPaymentURL.cshtml

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Remove the file extension from the NotificationURL. Razor Pages routing doesn't include file extensions.

Comment: Removing extension does not make any difference and SagePay still do not redirect back to my site.

Comment: Is the https you're using TLS 1.2, has a valid certificate etc.  Also, I don't believe that Sage Pay support shared SSL certs, with things like SNI, so this matters when behind something like cloud flare.  Essentially, Sage Pay are super paranoid when calling your end points.  If you can then try against a non-SSL endpoint to rule it out.

Comment: Yes, TLS 1.2 is being used and certificate is valid. My site has a dedicated ip address, it's not shared and not a wildcard